# Twilio compositions with different audio level per participant?

Tags: twilio, composition

(Yes, I am aware Twilio programmable video is reaching EOL... in the mean time....)

I want to create a composition of a meeting with 2x participants. However I want the composition to have different audio levels:

- Participant 1: 100% of original audio volume
- Participant 2: 50% of original audio volume

Can I set different audio volume per participant in the resulting composition?

Comment: Hey Brendan, to clarify, this is with Twilio programmable video recording compositions correct?

Comment: yes that's correct